# ggplot2 geom_area plots unexpectedly (ends in wrong place)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to plot the following data using `geom_area`.  The values are designed to be a x axis mirror image.  But the end of the plot for dog is not mirrored.

[image]

But as you can see from this data frame dog should end on x=100 and y=0 but it seems to end on x=100 and y=100 (see last row)

How can I make dog mirror cat exactly?

```
       x   y animal
1  100.0 100    cat
2   90.0  89    cat
3   84.0  85    cat
4   55.5  60    cat
5   28.3  37    cat
6   27.0  32    cat
7   18.0  25    cat
8    0.0   0    cat
9    0.0 100    dog
10  10.0  89    dog
11  16.0  85    dog
12  44.5  60    dog
13  71.7  37    dog
14  73.0  32    dog
15  82.0  25    dog
16 100.0   0    dog


dat <- structure(list(x = c(100, 90, 84, 55.5, 28.3, 27, 18, 0, 0, 10, 
    16, 44.5, 71.7, 73, 82, 100), y = c(100, 89, 85, 60, 37, 32, 
    25, 0, 100, 89, 85, 60, 37, 32, 25, 0), animal = c("cat", "cat", 
    "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "dog", 
    "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -16L), .Names = c("x", "y", "animal"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) + theme_bw() +
    geom_area(aes(x=x, y=y, group=animal, fill=animal), alpha=.3)
```

Oddly, if I subset just dog it plots correctly:

```
ggplot(subset(dat, animal=="dog")) + theme_bw() +
    geom_area(aes(x=x, y=y, group=animal, fill=animal), alpha=.3)
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_line` works properly, which may be a clue, as does subsetting just to 'cat'. I'm using ggplot2_1.0.0

Comment: Not sure if this has any meaning/relevance, but if you remove for example the first row of the data, it works as expected (but of course, cat looks different because of the missing data point..)

Comment: add `order=y` to the `aes` or `dat[order(dat$y), ]` (PS i have no explanation ;))

Comment: @user20650 I'm not sure why what you say works but it does and is probably the best answer here.  Can you put it down?

Comment: To the community is this a bug in ggplot2 or an error on my part to give order?

Comment: Yes, its strange, especially given sorting by `-y` gives another odd result. But please feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: I had an impression a similar behavior was reported some time ago, and it was explained like a likely bug in low-level routines `ggplot` uses under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error...
Another possible work around is to use `geom_ribbon`.

```
ggplot(dat) + theme_bw() +
geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = 0, ymax = y, group = animal, fill = animal, position = "stack"), alpha=.3)
```

This also gives the right plot[image: :]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you get that unexpected result. I got the same strange plot.

A possible workaround:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_area(data=dat[dat$animal=="dog",], aes(x=x, y=y, fill="red"), alpha=.3) +
  geom_area(data=dat[dat$animal=="cat",], aes(x=x, y=y, fill="blue"), alpha=.3) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Animal",breaks=c("red","blue"),labels=c("dog","cat")) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives the desired result:
[image]